# Cannot run jupyterhub with Sudospawner

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I can run jupyterhub for single user successfully but when I add  `c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'sudospawner.SudoSpawner'` 
it throws an error -

```
[E 2016-05-04 22:14:28.633 JupyterHub user:237] Unhandled error starting rhea's server: substring not found
[E 2016-05-04 22:14:28.642 JupyterHub web:1524] Uncaught exception GET /hub/user/rhea (::ffff:10.ip.***)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1445, in _execute
        result = yield result
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 493, in get
        yield self.spawn_single_user(current_user)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 312, in spawn_single_user
        yield gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=self.slow_spawn_timeout), f)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyterhub/user.py", line 247, in spawn
        raise e
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyterhub/user.py", line 228, in spawn
        yield gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=spawner.start_timeout), f)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sudospawner/spawner.py", line 83, in start
        reply = yield self.do(action='spawn', args=self.get_args(), env=self.get_env())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sudospawner/spawner.py", line 72, in do
        data_str = data_str[data_str.index('{'):data_str.rindex('}')+1]
    ValueError: substring not found
```

I tried to print the command jupyterhub trying to execute -

```
 ['sudo', '-u', 'rhea', '-nH', 'sudospawner']
```

datastr value is NULL (/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sudospawner/spawner.py", line 72, in do
            data_str = )

How to include and run sudospawner?

Thanks!

Comment: @minrk can you please check this?

Comment: I got the same error, but looking at the previous lines, I see that the process failed to open a PAM session. The unhandled error is a downstream effect of that.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://medium.com/@ybarraud/setting-up-jupyterhub-with-sudospawner-and-anaconda-844628c0dbee#.qdu3iato9) guide?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar set of downstream errors.

https://github.com/jupyterhub/sudospawner/blob/38992cfe1c4ede339305af5fc2a4782fdcf0356d/sudospawner/spawner.py#L84C9-L96

This comes when the result of trying to run a command through the sudospawner mediator process (the keyword arguments to `do()`) with `yield p.stdin.write(json.dumps(kwargs).encode('utf8'))`

In my case the problem was that the user running the jupyterhub process (which was called jupyterhub) didn't have a password set so therefore it couldn't successfully use `sudo` to spawn servers as different users.